# Typescript throws an "Object is possibly 'null'" error, despite type guard

Tags: typescript, types, null

I have a Typescript behaviour that I don't undestand, and I would like to have your input on it.

The compiler throws me an "*Object is possibly 'null'*" error even if there is a type check before.

Here is a simplified example:

```
class Bar {
  public a: string
}

class Foo {
  public bar: Bar | null
}

function functionDoingSomeStuff(callback: any) {
  callback()
}

const foo = new Foo()
if (!foo.bar) {
  return new Error()
}

console.log(foo.bar.a) // no compiler error thanks to the previous if

if (foo.bar) {
  functionDoingSomeStuff(() => {
    console.log(foo.bar.a) // a compiler error
  })
  console.log(foo.bar.a) // no compiler error
}
```

So why is the compiler warning me if I access to the possibly null property inside a function call, even if the catching *if* checks it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design. TypeScript doesn't assume type guards remain active in callbacks as making this assumption is dangerous.

## Fix

Capture the variable locally to ensure it doesn't get changed externally and TypeScript can easily understand that.

```
if (foo.bar) {
  const bar = foo.bar;
  functionDoingSomeStuff(() => {
    console.log(bar.a) // no compiler error
  })
}
```